# Frame size (352518912) larger than max length (15728640)! Exception while running sstableloader

Tags: cassandra-2.1

I’m trying to migrate data between two clusters on different networks. Ports: 7001,7199,9046,9160 are open between them. But port:7000 is not open. When I run sstableloader command, got the following exception.

Command:

```
:/a/cassandra/bin# ./sstableloader -d 192.168.98.99/abc/cassandra/data/apps/ads-0fdd9ff0a7d711e89107ff9c3da22254

Error/Exception: 

Could not retrieve endpoint ranges:
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Frame size (352518912) larger than max length (15728640)!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not retrieve endpoint ranges:
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader$ExternalClient.init(BulkLoader.java:342)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:156)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:109)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Frame size (352518912) larger than max length (15728640)!
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:137)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_describe_partitioner(Cassandra.java:1368)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.describe_partitioner(Cassandra.java:1356)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader$ExternalClient.init(BulkLoader.java:304)
        ... 2 more
```

In yaml file, `thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb:` is set to `15`. So I have increased its value to 40. Even after increasing the `thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb:` in yaml file, I’m getting the same error.

What could be the solution for this. Can somebody please help me with this??

Answer (score 0):

This was the initial error of 2.1.x sstableloader headaches on a secured cluster.

in our case we first forgot to add:

-tf org.apache.cassandra.thrift.SSLTransportFactory

along with the keystore/truststore params.

Then we ran into this:

[Cassandra sstableloader with ssl : PKIX error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906551/cassandra-sstableloader-with-ssl-pkix-error)

Then it worked. This was for both internode and client encryption enabled cluster